# Defining product topology in terms of basis elements?

Tags: general-topology

In the text that I have, we define the product topology $X \times Y$ on two topological spaces $(X, \mathcal{T}), (Y, \mathcal{U})$ as the topology generated by the basis $\{U \times V: U \in \mathcal{T}, V \in \mathcal{U}\}$.

Now, I am wondering:

Does anything go wrong if we define the product topology as the topology generated by the basis $\{B_1 \times B_2: B_1 \in \mathcal{B}_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}_2\}$, where $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$ are bases for $X$ and $Y$, respectively?

Comment: Nothing goes wrong: you get the same topology. Proving this is a good basic exercise.

Comment: Nice pun Brian :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because if $U\in\mathcal T$ and $V\in\mathcal U$, then $U$ can be written as an union of elements of $\mathcal B_1$ and $V$ can be written as an union of elements of $\mathcal B_2$. Therefore, $U\times V$ can be written as an union of elements of that set that you have mentioned.